# Redirect Only Mobile Phones And Not Tablets?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile, 51degrees

I'm have an ASP.NET MVC app and am using 51 Degrees for the first time. However, in my app I need to redirect ONLY mobile phones to the mobile version and NOT tablets?

Its not immediately obvious to me how I can achieve this using 51 Degrees? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to work through an install of this as well but I'm pretty sure if you add the below code into the redirect section within web.config or the 51Degrees.mobi.config file it will do the trick. This should cause anything NOT mobile to go to the regular site.

```
<location name="mobile" url="~/Mobile/Default.aspx">
      <add property="IsMobile" matchExpression="true"></add>
    </location>
```

Here is the link to the documentation regarding this:

http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/Foundation/UserGuide.aspx#Redirect